# Slow MYSQL query using COUNT and LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query the COUNT records and display records in MySQL.  While it displays fine and works correctly it is very slow.  I think this is in part due to the HTG_ScheduleRequest table being very large.  Is there a better way to arrange this query to speed this up?

```
SELECT HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber, 
       HTG_TechProps.EmpFirstName, 
       HTG_TechProps.EmpLastName,  
       HTG_TechProps.Veh_Number,
       COUNT(HTG_ScheduleRequest.ID) AS current_job 
    FROM HTG_TechProps 
        LEFT JOIN HTG_ScheduleRequest 
            ON HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber = HTG_ScheduleRequest.SSR 
                AND (HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE()) 
                AND HTG_ScheduleRequest.JobStatus = '3' 
    GROUP BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber 
    ORDER BY HTG_TechProps.EmpNumber ASC
```

Comment: no idea. you haven't provided any structural details about your db. but as a general rule of thumb: any field used in a "decision" context (where, join, sort, group) should have an index on it.

Comment: Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tabname` output for the two tables you have in play here. Indexing will be important.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to do the aggregation first(Query optimizers should do this, but they don't always do :) Replace HTG_ScheduleRequest with (SELECT SSR,count(*) from HTG_Schedule_request where (HTG_ScheduleRequest.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE()) AND HTG_ScheduleRequest.JobStatus = '3')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `EmpNumber` is unique, try this version (indexes follow the query):

```
SELECT tp.EmpNumber, tp.EmpFirstName, tp.EmpLastName, tp.Veh_Number,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM HTG_ScheduleRequest sr
        WHERE tp.EmpNumber = sr.SSR AND
              sr.ScheduleDateCurrent = CURDATE() AND
              sr.JobStatus = '3'
       )
FROM HTG_TechProps  tp
ORDER BY tp.EmpNumber ASC;
```

Before running the query, create these indexes:  `HTG_TechProps(EmpNumber)` and `HTG_ScheduleRequest(SSR, JobStatus, ScheduleDateCurrent)`.